# Format date SQL from dd/mm/yy hh:mm to yy-mm-dd

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, date-format

I have a table that's using this format for dates

dd/mm/yy hh:mm

| visit_date | visit datetime |
| --- | --- |
| #VALUE! | 01/01/2016 00:00 |
| #VALUE! | 02/01/2016 01:00 |

I need to change that format to

yy-mm-dd

So i can fill the visit_date Value with the proper value

**Expected output**

| visit_date | visit datetime |
| --- | --- |
| 2016-01-01 | 01/01/2016 00:00 |
| 2016-01-02 | 02/01/2016 01:00 |

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT    
     DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(visit, "%m/%d/%Y"), "%Y-%m-%d") 
FROM t1
```

Fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=93c4286c752026145a685af98c7773aa

Explanation: `STR_TO_DATE()` parses the 'laxed' `DATETIME` of your column. `DATE_FORMAT()` takes that and formats in the DATE format you're asking for.